# test jquery filter by using this code

Tags: jquery

I am new in jquery, i'm wanted to test jquery filter by using this code, but it doesn't work.

```
var y="find('li')";
$("ul").y.addClass("selected");
```

best regards,
Denis.

finally i got it :
  (new Function(  'wrappedSet='+ jQuery('#select').val()+';'  ))();
    wrappedSet.addClass('selected');

thank

Comment: What is your point here? You're trying to do some magic that I believe is not necessary. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It looks like they just want to be able to switch method/parameters in multiple places quickly for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to split it up into method and arguments

```
var method = "find";
var arguments = "li";

$("ul")[method](arguments).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
$("ul").find('li').addClass("selected");
```

But this will add the `selected` class to all the `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write entirely

```
$("ul").find("li").addClass("selected");
```

Or you can do

```
$("li", "ul").addClass("selected");
```

Comment: No you can find `selector` in `context` perf are better so you can do `$("li", "ul")` or `$("ul li")` there are the same but the first is better

Comment: `$("ul").find("li")` is faster than `$("li", "ul")`  http://jsperf.com/context-vs-find-vs-selector

Comment: Ok pas de problème, mais je n'avais pas compris le sens de votre interrogation.